# Página quebrada quando executa debug no Chrome

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, google-chrome

Quando faço o *debug* de um projeto *ASP.NET MVC* no *Visual Studio* direcionando para o browser *Chrome*, ele já abre a página quebrada:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Isso só ocorre quando o navegador está fechado. Quando ele já possui uma aba aberta, funciona perfeitamente. Por que isso acontece?

Comment: Defina melhor "página quebrada", por favor. Na imagem apenas não aparece o conteúdo. Isso gera algum erro no lado do servidor ou apenas o navegador que não é capaz de carregar a página? No `console` aparece algo? E o código fonte da página?

Comment: Então. O navegador para de funcionar basicamente. Não gera erro no lado do servidor. No navegador abrir a sua instância e abrir a minha página, se já existir uma página aberta, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Não dá para abrir o console, simplesmente não abre. Também não consigo ver o código fonte.